# How to run a web service using Axis2 through Mule

Tags: java, mule, soa

I wanna know that How to run a web service using Axis2 through Mule?

My Mule Version is 3.3.0.

This is Example_RMITest.xml

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" name="${serviceID}"
    host="${proxyHostname}" port="${proxyPort}" path="${serviceID}" 
    encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="入站HTTP" />               
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://192.168.98.48:9080/JKService/webservices/JKService?wsdl"
    encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="出站HTTP" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Axis support has been abandoned in Mule 3.x.

Mule now uses CXF exclusively for both exposing and consuming web services.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I have been run a webService using Axis2, I want to put it on the mule, it should be how to do? Thanks.

Comment: Is it JAX-WS compatible?